# Border radius being displayed in select2 input group with checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox, jquery-select2-4

I've spent hours trying to get rid of the border radius on my select2 append checkbox. As of now the dropdown is displayed with a checkbox on the left. The problem is that there seems to be a border radius between the two input group elements, something similar to the [image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2598704/4386822/e0b86d50-43d4-11e4-82d7-7f86fe4d27e8.png). The solution proposed was adding the input-group select2-bootstrap-prepend class to the wrapper element which doesn't work for me.

The html is as follows

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel-body">
       <b>Region</b><br>
            <div class="input-group select2-bootstrap-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked>
                </span>
                <select id="select2-single-append" class=" region">
                </select>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

View the running example from [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/senior01/kLchxehz/2/)

Comment: Please provide your CSS also, the relevant parts.

Comment: I haven't  made any customizations to the css files since I'm referencing the respective files from a cdn.

Comment: Can you provide a live example?

Comment: I've added a link to a working example. I hope its sufficient

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
    border-radius:0 0.25rem 0.25rem 0;
}
```

see this fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/grassog/kLchxehz/25/ (relevant css at the bottom of the css portion)

Comment: Thanks. I've added the css to my custom css file and it still didn't work. I've ended up placing the css in a style tag in the page for it to work. I didnt expect that but it'll do for now